# Camera keeps sliding up when riding the horse

Tags: the-witcher-3

When I'm riding the horse in Witcher 3, the camera keeps sliding up so that I'm eventually facing downwards, and can barely see what's in front of me. I'm playing the game on PC but with an Xbox 360 controller.

Anyone know why it's doing this, and how I can fix it?

Something I noticed. Normally, on PC, you can switch between keyboard and controller very easily. If you are using the controller and you hit a key on the keyboard, the icons will change to keyboard icons. But once the aforementioned bug happens (it doesn't happen immediately when loading a save), then the icons no longer switch between controller and keyboard. So it seems like that is related.

So loading a save seems to fix it, at least temporarily.

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem. I'm pretty sure that I've looked everywhere for a solution but to no avail. I found a post about this same problem on Cdpr's forums but no one has responded there either. Here's a link to the post,

http://forums.cdprojektred.com/threads/39891-PS4-Xbox-One-Auto-Center-Bug-(Camera)

Comment: Excellent thanks for confirming. Glad to know it's not just me. For now, my workaround is to save and reload when it starts happening. It usually happens after about an hour of gameplay until I reload, so it's not that big of a deal, but it's still a nuisance.

Comment: @Gary posting an comment there, stating that this also affects pc might be a smart move.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, as irritating as it is to wait through the loading screens, I found just saving while on Roach and then reloading fixed the issue.